# Redirect for specific query string value

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement, web

How do i make it redirect when its on `article?id=1` to `index.php`
this is just an example if you dont understand this maybe this example is better

```
<?php
    if (header('location: article?id=1'==1)) 
    {
    header('location:index.php')
    }
?>
```

Sorry for my noob coding
and thanks to you all for helping me 
i have tried some different things that i thought might work but i want to know from someone who knows more than me

Comment: `header()` OUTPUTS a header. it has no return value and cannot be used to match/test against anyhing. http://php.net/header. You probably want `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '...')` or similar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP puts all query string keys and values in the `$_GET` superglobal associative array:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']==1) {
  header('Location: http://example.com/index.php');
}
```

Also, be sure to use the full URL with `Location:` headers.  While most browsers will work without it just fine, it's good to be compliant with the RFCs.

Comment: Dosen't do anything when i reload the page it doesen't redirect me
why might it not work?

Comment: @EasierNameToReplyTo Make a page with only this code, and let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']==1){
 header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) this way:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 1) {

    header('location: http://example.com/index.php');
 }
```

Comment: Doesen't work plz help it just does not redirect me any other way i could do it